# How to show JSON response in iPhone using the objective c by dynamically adding " \" to the keys?

Tags: ios, json, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I am having a sample code which helps me to print the JSON response. In this I manually added the \ slash symbol before keys and values so it helps me to print the JSON . The code is :

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"person\": {\"name\":\"James\",\"age\":\"24\"}},{\"person\": {\"name\":\"ray\",\"age\":\"70\"}}]";
```

Now the problem is once the JSON string gets longer I have to manually add the \ before every key.

Can someone help of how I can add **""** before the keys as shown in the code above using some looping code?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Replace " with \"

Comment: @Cy-4AH Can you please help with the sample code?

Comment: Which sample code? You need do it only for static strings that you manually type into source file.

Comment: @Cy-4AH i mean i cannot directly add json string to static strings because it will give error in objective c. I need to add \ to each key value before the assigning of strings

Comment: Then open text editor and find and replace " with \"

Comment: @User1075 - it's not clear what you are asking... Are you ***typing*** that into your `.m` source code? Or, are you receiving some json data from somewhere, and you want to print it with added `\\` chars to the debug console (or setting it as a label text)?

Comment: Right now i am typing for testing purpose but i want to make it flexible because once i get json data from somewhere i need to print it with '\'. Thanks for commenting and looking for help @DonMag

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you're trying to do - but maybe this will work...

Use:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement;
```

The `target` will be `"`, and you'll need to escape it like this:

```
@"\""
```

The `replacement` will be `\"`, escaped like this:

```
@"\\\""
```

So, this:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"person\": {\"name\":\"James\",\"age\":\"24\"}},{\"person\": {\"name\":\"ray\",\"age\":\"70\"}}]";
NSLog(@"%@", [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""]);
```

will output this to the debug console:

```
2022-10-11 12:35:58.958881-0400 YourProj[6562:7795515] [{\"person\": {\"name\":\"James\",\"age\":\"24\"}},{\"person\": {\"name\":\"ray\",\"age\":\"70\"}}]
```

When receiving json from remote, it might look like this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *js = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", [js stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""]);
```